# Python: create child object with parent reference in python

Tags: python, oop

In Python, I am not able to find how to create child object with parent reference.

```
class Parent:
    .....

class Child(Parent):
    .....

#how to achieve this?
Parent p = Child()
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary for you to achieve this in dynamically-typed Python. Don't mix Python and Java! ^_^

Comment: Thanks for quickly clearing my doubt!! Question of a newbie to python..